How to use a custom object and Omni-flow to block MIAW IP Address?
The Salesforce documentation mentions omni flow and custom object as alternate solution to block IP address for MIAW but there is no documentation with further steps listed. Has anyone implemented this alternative and could shed some light into the steps?
